# C# Send PDF to printer

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I have to send a PDF file ( CAD drawing ) to a specific printer in the network. I also have to set the papersize for the document.

Has anyone an idea how to code this in C# without using any 3rd party library ?

Tried this => https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322091/how-to-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-visual-c--net
But this is not working ( only printing some cryptical signs ).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use a 3rd party, you can use this pure C# code which created a `Process` with arguments to print any file:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "print",
    // Path to your PDF
    FileName = pathToPDF
};
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that i have to pass the papersize.

Answer (score -1):

First find your default printer and set it to a variable.

Then compare your default printer to the one you want to print to.

If different, set your default printer to the desired printer.

Print your document.

Reset the default printer back to what it was.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

static class RawPrinter
   {
  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

  public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);

  public static string GetDefaultPrinter()
  {
     string sDefaultPrintername = "";
     PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
     foreach (string sPrinter in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
     {
        settings.PrinterName = sPrinter;
        if (settings.IsDefaultPrinter)
        {
           sDefaultPrintername = sPrinter;
           break;
        }
     }
     return sDefaultPrintername;
  }
  public void Print(string sFileNmae, string sPrinterName)
  {
     try
     {
        string sPrinterDefaultTemp = RawPrinter.GetDefaultPrinter();
        if (sPrinterDefaultTemp != sPrinterName)
        {
           RawPrinter.SetDefaultPrinter(sPrinterName);
        }
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
           p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
           {
              CreateNoWindow = true,
              Verb = "print",
              FileName = sFileNmae,
              WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
           };
           p.Start();
        };
        if (sPrinterDefaultTemp != sPrinterName)
        {
           RawPrinter.SetDefaultPrinter(sPrinterDefaultTemp);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ".Print()");
     }
  }
}
```